# Database table design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I have a table of property listings. I need to add cities to these listings. Is it best practice to split a list of cities into it's own table?

I would like the user when adding a new property to be able to select from a list of cities.

By the way this is a Rails project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cities lookup table makes sense in this case.

This will also allow you to add more information for each city in the future, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one city per property, there is nothing terribly wrong with putting it in the properties table.  If there are more, there is no good choice but to use a cities table.

Alternatively, if you want to pick the cities from a drop down list with no additions allowed, having a cities table may be a good idea. If you do that then you probably want to store the cityid not the city name in the property table. That way when someone changes the name of a city (which admittedly probably doesn't happen very often) you only have to change one record.  Of course if you do have a cities table, you must have a foreign key and make sure city_id is indexed in the properties table to maintain your data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is generally a best practice to normalize your database schema such that you are not repeating the same city names in multiple property listing records in your property listing table.

There are cases where you would want to denormalize for performance reasons.  I would not consider your case to be one of these cases until it proves itself to be (i.e. table reads become very slow.)  Even then, there are optimizations you could undertake prior to denormalizing your schema.

Comment: Putting the city in its own table has nothing to do with normalization. Not doing so has nothing to do with denormalization. That doesn't necessarily make either thing right or wrong - but you ought to be clear about what the reasoning is. There's no indication that the OP's schema isn't already normalized.

Comment: @dportas True, my response would have better served the question if it had included examples of a normalized and denormalized schema, indicating that I thought he was asking which one he should use.